# Using exceptions in a .dll, makes any executable using it crash

Tags: gcc, dll, shared-libraries, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a homemade library: `mylib.dll`

Within this library, C++ exceptions have recently been introduced - all are caught inside the library, i.e. none are thrown out to be caught by the users of the library.

Historically, this library has been statically linked with *libgcc* and *libstdc++* - but as soon as exceptions were introduced, any executable using the shared library would crash on any exception (caught or not) inside `mylib.dll`.

The executable - let's call it `main.exe` - is dynamically linked with the library like this:

```
ld [args] -Wl,--start-group mylib.dll.a <other libraries> -Wl,--end-group ...
```

As long as `mylib.dll` is statically linked with the std libraries, any exception will inside `mylib.dll`  will make `main.exe` crash.

My guess is that this is because there are now several instances of the std library for exceptions (one for the lib and one for the executable) - and then it won't be able to handle it properly, perhaps because of stack unwinding?

It does work by **not** statically linking *libgcc* and *libstdc++* into `mylib.dll`, as expected. Here, they are both linked dynamically, and `main.exe` works just fine with the exception handling inside `mylib.dll`

It did work *also* statically linking *libgcc* and *libstdc++* into `main.exe` as well. Maybe this is because the exceptions were contained inside `mylib.dll` - and then it wouldn't work if they were thrown from inside the `.dll` and caught in `main.exe`? This is only speculation, I don't know.

In any case, it seems that one should **never** statically link any standard library into a homemade `.dll`, and always dynamically link the std libraries in this case. This is what I will go with from now on.

I would though still like to understand why it crashes in my case, since the exceptions are contained within `mylib.dll`